# Multi level Nav Menu Balzor server side application

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Working on a blazor server application and trying to make the multi level Navigation menu

Under Shared Component Navmenu.razor file, i added the code  which is copied from bootstrap

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

After running this changes the menu item seems to be added to layout , but dropdown behaviour is not working

After further search and adding jquery library to the _Host.cshtml , head section like below

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

the menu managed to show the behaviour of dropdown

Is this is recommended to use jquery inside the blazor  but colors or styles seems to be overridden  as in picture
[image]

Is really no easy-way to make a multi level Nav Menu in Blazor ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your problem is you should make a component out of it.

For example,

Start by creating a component with a boolean and a string.

Then create an element and give it the @onclick attribute. When the user clicks on the element, it fires the onclick event and it switches the boolean value to the opposite of what it was.

Finally, a string property tracks the boolean value and outputs the appropriate string that contains the style needed to show or hide a particular element.

*CollapsableMenuItem.razor*

```cs
<button @onclick="ToggleVisibility" class="btn btn-link" style="cursor:pointer;">Click me</button>
<br />
<span class="nav-item" style="@_style">
    I'm invisible until you click on the button
</span>

@code {
 private bool _collapsed;

 private string _style 
   => _collapsed ? "visibility:visible;" : "visibility:hidden;";

 public Task ToggleVisibility() {
   _collapsed = !_collapsed;
   return Task.CompletedTask;
 }
}
```

I created this .NET Fiddle to see it in action:

https://blazorfiddle.com/s/229e32g4

Comment: The menu seems to be working , but still not sure how the styles like selected menu class etc will be handled with this approach ?

Comment: Also if we have to keep 2 or more categories of submenus we have ot maintain more variables

Comment: example is not compiling anymore

Answer (score 1):

As Dennis mentioned, you can build a component out of it.
However, if you are fine with the basic functionality offered by bootstrap, just go with it. I have used it extensively without any issues. Also,

1. There is no harm in using JavaScript with Blazor. A lot of libraries use it all the time. For some browser interactions (page refresh, getting viewport size etc) you have to use JavaScript.
2. If you use bootstrap 5, there is no jQuery. It's pure JavaScript
3. Most importantly, it's painful to get animation right in blazor. While you will get the core collapse/expand functionality very easily in blazor, the animation is tricky.

Finally, your styles are wonky because there is a conflict in styling between nav-link that comes bundled with the visual studio template and nav-link as described in bootstrap. Keep one of your choice. You will find the template css under the razor file of the menu component. Delete or mark !important depending on style that you want to keep.

Comment: Any thoughts of using libraries like https://mudblazor.com/ or https://www.matblazor.com/ or something similar which are free open source at this moment Seems like can generate more colourful UI with them , Does that cause any performance issues on production time

Comment: I dont think so. These libraries are written by people who are very knowledgeable about Blazor.  These would be definitely more efficient than a beginner writing on his own!  The only problem is that sometimes, the UI components do not serve the specific requirement that you have.  But that applies to *any* UI library on any framework, not just Blazor.

Comment: I'd argue for @MayurEkbote 's point and also add the following: Blazor is intended as a way for developers to create reusable UI components. If you are going to use the libraries available, do so only if you really cannot do it yourself. There is great benefit to be gained if you can build your own components and using libraries prevents a beginner from learning to be more proficient in using Blazor. Also, community developed libraries are prone to change and likely only a few of them last for years to come. You don't want a library in a production app that stops support out of nowhere.

Comment: I felt blazor in its pure form is lagging lot of things to use them blindly. Few examples: A dropdown menu to navigation bar , a select dropdown with searchable feature , support for a dialog and so many most common use cases

Comment: I had raised this long ago, but the PM for Blazor categorically denied to build any such thing. From their perspective, it's a UI management framework. They want third parties to take care of the specific market needs. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/23559